# Books recommended for learning about all of the different branches of Sanatana philosophy in brief

Tags: scripture, philosophy, book-recommendation

Which books do you recommend for learning about all of the different branches of Sanatana philosophy in brief?

- I have a copy of **Sarva Darsana Sangraha** written by 14th century Hindu scholar Madhava Acharya, where he lists the major schools of Sanatana philosphy and writes commentary on them.
- Somebody recommended me **The Principal Upanishads** by Dr. S. Radhakrishnan. How is that book?

Please recommend me some books and/or scriptures where I can learn about many  different branches of Sanatana philosphy in brief.

Comment: try https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: Sarva darshan sangrah is a classic book. Anither book is prasthaan-bheda by Shri Madhusudan Sarasvati.The copy of sarva darshan sangrah which I have is not good quality. Can you please share your copy with me?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande I got it from academia website. Can't find the link right now. However, it is available on Gutenberg website. Here is the link- https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34125 . See if you are satisfied with the quality. If not, let me know. I shall try something else.

Answer (score 4):

Sarva Darśana Saṃgraha​ of Vidyāraṇya Mādhavācārya​ is one of the good one which describes various philosophies. Apart from this, I'm aware of two other works of similar in nature i.e describes various Darshanas (philosophies):

1. [**Sarva Siddhāṃta Saṃgraha**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.311086)​ of Ādi Śaṃkarācārya​. It contains following chapters regarding various philosophies:

   1. Lokāyatika Pakṣa​
   2. Āharta​ Paksha
   3. Bauddha​ Paksha
   4. Vaiśeṣika Paksha
   5. Naiyāyika​ Paksha
   6. Prabhākara​ Paksha
   7. Bhaṭṭācārya​ Paksha
   8. Sāṅkhya​ Paksha
   9. Patañjali Paksha
   10. Vedavyāsa​ Paksha
   11. Vedānta Paksha
2. [**Prasthāna Bheda**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/snsastri/PrasthAnabheda-Engl.pdf) of Madhusūdana Sarasvatī. It is a short work discusses about various scriptures and about Mimansa, Vedanta, PAshupata and PancharAtra in short.

Answer (score 4):

1. https://archive.org/details/historyofindianp04dasguoft/page/n8/mode/2up
   A history of Indian philosophy..5 volumes.
   by Dasgupta, Surendranath, 1885-1952; Dasgupta, Surama
2. Sharirik bhashya I.e. shankarbhashya of Sankaracharya - the bhashya on Brahmasutra.

And many more books in Hindi or other Indian languages.

Comment: thanks. I can't find an ebook of Sharirik Bhashya in English. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

These books are best in my view.

- [Meeting God: Elements of Hindu Devotion By Stephen Huyler, Steven P. Huyler](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1K0XGaVANP4UqL1BRTMzFGa7x0zrzAKDH6D_a2gkgWhk/mobilebasic)
- [Light of truth (Satyarth Prakash) by Rishi Dayanand](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/)
- [Autobiography of a Yogi By Paramhansayoagananda.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Autobiography-of-a-Yogi-by-Paramahansa-Yogananda.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwin5sn60PDnAhUyguYKHT6yCewQFjAAegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw32riaCqmNNObkVTRgpgY1v)